# Using RegEx with Powershell ForEach an replace

Tags: regex, powershell, replace, foreach

I need to replace some characters in a line of a logfile.

One Part of this logfile is defined as:

```
(sha1: b2ac534797bceb683ee5db85fcd4bbb885c4a205, md5: bb4fd7d270c523bb5d1c6c18e9b42801, sha256: e5b9090d2f0efd5aa99102aae223b4e346c6c8229d4931d08bbb5d1d43146cfd)
```

I want to replace the whole string with a simple `;`

```
ForEach {$_ -replace "\' (SHA-1:^[a-z][0-9]$ , MD5:^[a-z][0-9]$ , SHA-256:^[a-z][0-9]$ ",";"}
```

But that doesn't work. Get the message, the pattern is not valid.

Comment: You want to remove the hash algorithm too?

Comment: Yes, I don't need this part of the log for my further work.

Answer (score 2):

The target string can be described as `(...)` where `...` is a group consisting of `<algoName>: <hash>` and an optional trailing sequence `,` , repeated 3 times:

```
$replaced = Get-Content path\to\file.log |ForEach-Object {
  $_ -replace '\(((sha|md)\d+: [a-f0-9]+(, )?)+\)', ';'
}

$replaced |Set-Content path\to\output.txt
```

If the log file is relatively small (eg. KBs instead of MBs), you can also apply `-replace` directly to output from `Get-Content`:

```
@(Get-Content path\to\file.log) -replace '\(((sha|md)\d+: [a-f0-9]+(, )?)+\)', ';' |Set-Content path\to\output.txt
```

Comment: That was fast lol. I thought the hashes were separated not one entire string ‍♂️

Comment: Nicely done; two suggestions: you mention `3` times, but the regex simply uses `+`, which can be confusing (I looked in vain for `{3}`)). Since line breaks don't matter here, you can even do `Get-Content -Raw`, which will be substantially faster (though then requires `-NoNewLine` when writing the result to a file).